# Are Linux node modules different from the Windows ones?

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, cmd, npm

I used the Windows 10 bash subsystem to run a React app. When I installed the node modules and ran the app from the bash all worked fine, but when I tried running it from windows terminal (having installed all the global packages and using the same node version) I got `'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

When I removed `node_modules` and reinstalled them through Windows terminal, all worked fine. So my question is: are some modules written differently for different platforms? Will it cause errors working from sometimes from bash and sometimes from CMD on Windows?